# How I get the javascript object I want from the javascript object I have and pass that to a nested (complex) body using Axios to post an API

Tags: javascript, object, axios

New using Axios. I need help with the body formatting of my Axios post in React Js

My code:

```
  body: JSON.stringify(
    {
      quote_timestamp: timestamp,
      number_of_products: state.length,
    } &&
    state.map((product) => ({
      quote_timestamp: timestamp,
      number_of_products: state.length,
      products: {
        cat_Number: product.cat,
        product_Name: product.Name,
      },
    }))
  )
```

At the moment it is printing the data, as it maps each product like this:

```
body [
  {
    quote_timestamp: '7/24/2022, 11:25:27 PM',
    number_of_products: 3,
    products: {
      cat: 'AB1',
      Name: 'Alpha'
    }
  },
  {
    quote_timestamp: '7/24/2022, 11:25:27 PM',
    number_of_products: 3,
    products: {
      cat: 'AB2',
      Name: 'Beta'
    }
  },
  {
    quote_timestamp: '7/24/2022, 11:25:27 PM',
    number_of_products: 3,
    products: {
      cat: 'AB3',
      Name: 'Gamma'
    }
  }
]
```

However, I would like the format to be such that the timestamp and number of products are printed once and then maps through all selected products. Like this below:

```
    body[ {
        quote_timestamp: '7/24/2022, 11:25:27 PM',
        number_of_products: 3,
        products: { 

    { cat: 'AB1', Name:'Alpha' }, 
    
    { cat: 'AB2' Name:'Beta' }.
    
    { cat: 'AB3' Name:'Gamma' }
 }
}
```

Comment: so, not really a question about reactjs, json, api or axios - it's really just *"how do I get the javascript object I want from the javascript object I have?"* ... first issue I see is `{some object} && {some other object}` will result in JSON.stringify processing `{some other object}` ONLY - however, the output you WANT is not possible ... should `products:` be an Array rather than an Object?

Comment: How can I get JSON.stringify to process both ? Any suggestion?

Comment: Both? no you mean you want a single object to stringify ... also, *the output you WANT is not possible* - and one more thing, the code you've shown wouldn't produce the output you've shown, since the "products" object should have `cat_Number`, `product_Name` and `Price` properties, not `cat` and `Name` ... so, not sure what your real code is, but it's not this

Comment: I have amended it to just show the structure. But it is meant to be cat number and product name. I have edited the code.

Comment: no, you haven't yet asked for output that could possibly be produced by JSON.stringify .... what you want is not valid ...  `[` with no `]` ... `products: { { .... }, { .... } }` is not valid either - it's difficult to help you if what you want is an object that is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get close to what you want, you would simply do this

```
JSON.stringify({
    quote_timestamp: timestamp,
    number_of_products: state.length,
    total_price: total,
    products: state.map((product) => ({
        cat_Number: product.Cat_Number,
        product_Name: product.Product_Name,
        Price: product.mockPrice,
    })),
})
```

Hope that helps

edit: oops, typo

Comment: This is very close to the outcome I was looking for thank you!

Comment: However, it does not print the object details.
Here is the output I get:
`body` `{`
  `quote_timestamp: '7/25/2022, 1:28:06 AM',`
  `number_of_products: 2,`
  `total_price: 2001,`
  `products: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ]`
`}`

Comment: sorry, ... typo on my part - try now @mstarluk